# Should we have a "misspecification" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

I just read [this very interesting question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274815/1352) and wanted to add the "obviously relevant but missing" [misspecification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misspecification) tag - only to notice that we don't have it. Which I find surprising. We have quite a few questions on ["misspecification"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=misspecification+is%3Aq) or ["misspecify"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=misspecify+is%3Aq) or ["misspecified"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=misspecified+is%3Aq), some of them pretty well upvoted - but no tag.

Does anyone have strong feelings for or against adding the tag to these questions (a few questions at a time, in order not to bump-flood the landing page), or even have a tag wiki and/or excerpt proposal?

Comment: If it ends up being created, make sure it will born with a nice tag excerpt. Perhaps propose one in question body, or as an answer.

Comment: [model-misspecification] could be a more explicit & clear name, but then perhaps it's getting too long...

Comment: Definitely should be created!

Comment: Looking at some of those questions it does seem to cover a wide variety of situations. Having a more explicit tag as @amoeba suggested might be a good idea and then not tag all of the ones which your search found.

Comment: I went ahead and made the tag.  Retagged a few, much more is needed. Have a look at my proposed tag wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I went ahead and made the tag (cf., [misspecification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/misspecification)).  I retagged some, many more are needed.  Have a look at my proposed [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/misspecification/info).

I don't have any posts so far in the tag, so I cannot propose synonyms.  Please go ahead and propose synonyms, if you have enough upvoted posts in the tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I looked at the tag - looks good to me, maybe someone else can edit if they think it's necessary.